# Error initialising Repository bean in Spring Data JDBC. Auto configuration not working for Spring data Jdbc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jdbc

I am creating custom data sources and when I am trying to create a repository, the bean is not getting initialized properly and I am getting an error as -

className":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","methodName":"report","log":"Application failed to start due to an exception","stackTrace":"org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.RelationalMappingContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

I only want to read information from the table so I haven't defined any @Table and @Column in my dto.

The Autoconfiguration is not working for my spring-boot-JDBC project.

Here is my configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "DSProperties1")
  @ConfigurationProperties("datasource1.spring.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties2() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean(name = "DSProperties2")
  @ConfigurationProperties("datasource1.spring.datasource")
  public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties1() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  @Bean(name = "DataSource1")
  @ConfigurationProperties("datasource1.spring.datasource.hikari")
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource1(
          @Qualifier("DSProperties1") DataSourceProperties dsProperties) {
    return dsProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "DataSource2")
  @ConfigurationProperties("datasource2.spring.datasource.hikari")
  public DataSource dataSource2(
          @Qualifier("DSProperties2") DataSourceProperties dsProperties) {
    return dsProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }

  }
```

Comment: Did you include the sqlserver jdbc driver in your list of dependencies.

Comment: yeah thats been included   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

The deleted part of your question shows that you have more than one `DataSource` configured.
This makes it impossible for autoconfiguration to proceed.

Either declare exactly one `DataSource` or configure Spring Data JDBC yourself.
You can do that by extending `AbstractJdbcConfiguration`

Comment: ok, I have readded the part. I have tried to extend the AbstractJdbcConfiguration in the above configuration. Now I am getting an exception creating dailect bean as Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect'